# Join table by string matching in Hive or Impala or Pig

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, impala

I have two tables `A` and `B`, where `B` is huge (20 million by 300) and `A` is of moderate size (300k by 10). `A` contains one column that is address and `B` contains 3 columns that can be put together to form a proper street address. For example, in `A`, the address column could be:

```
id  | Address
-----------
233 | 123 Main St
```

and in `B` we could have:

```
Number  |  Street_name  | Street_suffix | Tax
------------------------------------------------
123     |  Main         | Street        | 320.2
```

I want to join them using string matching similar to `LIKE` with something like the following:

```
select A.id, B.Tax
from A
  left join B
    on A.Address **contains** B.Number
    and A.Address **contains** B.Street_name;
```

Basically I am trying to match the records by saying that if `A`'s address contains `B`'s number and street_name, then I say they are the same address (In reality, I also have city, state and zip code. But I chose to ignore those for illustration purposes).

The 2 contains part is something I am not sure how to implement. Any ideas?

I am on Cloudera's Hue Hadoop distribution, where I have access to Hive (1.1.0, unfortunately because 1.2.0 has Levenshtein distance function), Impala (v2.3.0) and Pig (0.12.0-cdh5.5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join with equality conditions only, **but** -
You can **cross join** and **filter**.

```
select      A.id, B.Tax
from        A cross join B
where       concat(' ',A.Address,' ') like concat('% ',cast(B.Number as string),' %')
        and concat(' ',A.Address,' ') like concat('% ',B.Street_name,' %')
;
```

---

Demo

```
hive> create table A (id int,Address string);
OK
hive> create table B (number int,Street_name string,Street_suffix string,tax decimal(12,2));
OK
hive> insert into A values (233,'123 Main St');
Query ID = ...
OK
hive> insert into B values (123,'Main','Street',320.2);
Query ID = ...
OK
hive> select      A.id, B.Tax
    > from        A cross join B
    > where       concat(' ',A.Address,' ') like concat('% ',cast(B.Number as string),' %')
    >         and concat(' ',A.Address,' ') like concat('% ',B.Street_name,' %')
    > ;
Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[8][bigTable=b] in task 'Stage-3:MAPRED' is a cross product
Query ID = ...
OK
233 320.2
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive join have limitation you can use join with equality conditions only.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

If you could logically explode A.Address column in such away that it matches table B column format then you can use join on that column ....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JOINs in hive only work with equality conditions

[Refer here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)

So you can try the where condition with like and concat operation like below

```
select A.id, B.Tax
from A,B where A.Address LIKE CONCAT('%',cast(B.Number as string),'%') 
               AND
               A.Address LIKE CONCAT('%',B.Street_name,'%')
```