# Efficient way to join big table by sub strings using hive/ impala or other ways

Tags: string, hadoop, join, hive, impala

I have 2 tables `tabl1`:

```
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
| att1  |  att2  | att3   | att4     |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
|  abcd | ava012 | df012f | afsdaldf |
.......
```

and `tabl2`:

```
+----+
| val|
+----+
| 012|
...
```

`tabl2` contains numbers that can be substring in one or more of the 4 columns of `tabl1`.
The both tables are big tables contains millions of records. 
I tried to concatenate `tabl1` columns and search in it but the query never ends. 
Is there an efficient way to do it. Maybe to transform the whole table into one `txt` file and search in it?
Following also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052959/join-table-by-string-matching-in-hive-or-impala-or-pig)
Here are some examples of my trials (both in Hive):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
from tabl1 a, tabl2 b
where  
instr (
concat ( (cast (a.att1 as string), (cast (a.att2 as string), 
(cast (a.att3 as string), (cast (a.att4 as string) ) , (cast (b.val as string) ) ) > 0
```

or

```
  SELECT a.*, b.*
    from tabl1 a, tabl2 b
    where  
    concat ( (cast (a.att1 as string), (cast (a.att2 as string), 
(cast (a.att3 as string), (cast (a.att4 as string) ) 
like  concat ('%',(cast (b.val as string),'%')
```

There are some more with `REGEX` but endless runtime...

Comment: Is there only a single token containning digits in an attribute? e.g. is `df012fxxx013yyy014zzz` a valid attribute? if so, are you expecting `tabl2.val` to be the first/last/any token?

Comment: do you want do a full join operation ? is not very clear how you link the records between those 2 tables .

Comment: Thanks you all. There is not necessarily single token. @lake - As for the join - if val is contained in one of the tabl1 attributes it is a matched  join.

Comment: Is it it always in a known pattern (e.g. digits)?

Comment: The val is always numbers, the columns in tabl2 are alpha numeric characters.

Comment: And you are looking for a full match, e.g. `012` will match `a012b` but not `a0123b`?

Comment: Yes. If I have var with value 012 I would like to find 012 inside one of the attributes (in att1 or att2 or att3 or att4). Practically if val is in att1 (inside, part of the string) for instance, then there is a match and no need to check other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  *

from           (select  *
                from    tabl1 t1
                        lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(trim(regexp_replace(concat_ws(',',att1,att2,att3,att4),'\\D+',' ')),'(?<=^| )(?<token>.*?) (?=.*(?<= )\\k<token>(?= |$))',''),' ')) e as val
                ) t1

        join    tabl2 t2

        on      t2.val = 
                t1.val
```